# VB.NET Newby - datatables best practice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

long time reader first time contributor!

I have been writing asp.net code for just over a year coming from a classic asp background. My question is... what is best practice for memory resident datatables?

ie... I have written a few ecommerce sites which on application start loads all products, product variations etc into a global datatable in a vb.class file, throughout the site it references this datatable for searches and filters etc... the theory being memory resident information would be faster than database access..

this seemed to work ok so i have used this method on other sites - but - is this the correct way to use datatables rather than have the site go directly to the database for the latest information in various places?

should i use this method everywhere possible ie... news lists, testimonials lists, site pages and content etc... or should i just load from the database where i need as i would classic asp ( likely most pages if info is going into the navigation ) - the latter way means the data is always up to date - instead of having the odd datatable error where the admin has deleted a product / page /record and the datatable hasn't been updated to remove the record.

in short... what is common practice?

thanks!

Comment: You'll run into various threading issues if you use a global/shared `DataTable` in ASP.NET. You need to SyncLock it which will effectively serializing all access to the dataset/datatable turning your multi-user web application into a one-user-at-a-time type of application. **Use the database instead**. If you store the table in `Session` instead `Cache`/`Shared` you need one table per user which is unnecessary and also bears the risk of race-conditions or outdated data.

Comment: There are built in caching classes that should give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Tarik: the `Cache` is basically similar to a `Shared` object. Don't use it for data in a multithreading environment (see my comment above).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would not be so dogmatic. If such things as product lists are pretty much static AND it is justified by a significant performance gain, then why not caching after taking the necessary precautions through synchronization.  That said, with enough memory, disk caching at the O.S. level might offer the same performance without headaches.

Comment: @Tarik: the performance gain is negligible compared  to the database, but it's much more vulnerable to issues which are very difficult to fix or even notice. _Today_ it is static but tomorrow it can be changed from the app or even from other systems. You need to refactor a lot of code if you have to fix this later. Write a robust app from the ground up.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree. Unless absolutely necessary,  stick to retrieveing the data directly from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - not sure I fully understand synclock etc... but getting the info from the database on a perpage basis rather than an application start > memory resident datatable basis makes sense - although I dont understand the logic behind: 10 users hit the home page and each time the page will connect to the database multiple times to retrieve the same information and put it in a datatable / dataview to produce the same output for each of the 10 users... seems like a lot of work to get to the same place.